# jQuery AJAX plugins with Flask

Tags: jquery, python, flask

A lot of jQuery plugins have AJAX support, for example the [autocomplete jQuery UI plugin](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default) or the form [validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

Most of the documentation about the AJAX support of the plugin is shown using PHP:

**Autocomplete:**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
        }
    });
});
```

**Validation plugin:**

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: "check-email.php"
    }
  }
});
```

My question is know **how can this be done using the Flask Framework?** And what type of object do I have to return?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure the plugin to use one of your app's URLs, e.g. `source: '/search'`, and define the view with this route:

```
@app.route('/search')
def search():
    # If it's a GET request, the data will be provided as request.args.  In case
    # of POST or PUT you'll have to use request.data or request.json (depends on
    # how the plugin is sending the data).
    query = request.args.get('query')
    # Perform the search here.
    results = ...
    # What to return here depends on what the plugin expects, consult the docs
    # to figure this out.  Most likely it'll be some JSON encoded data structure.
    return jsonify(results=results)
```